# python os.system error: "global name 'output' is not defined"

Tags: python, os.system

Newbie here.  any help would be appreciated..

I am writing a cgi script that runs a tcp pcap diagnostic tool.  if I would run the command in bash it would look like:

```
/home/fsoft/cap/capnostic -r 38350 /home/fsoft/brad.pcap > 38350
```

So I am trying to do it in python:

```
output = os.system('/home/fsoft/cap/capnostic -r' + port + directory+filename '>' + jobdir+filename
```

I have a feeling the '>' is messing things up..  But I can't seem to find the right syntax..  Also once I get the command correctly will I just be able to print the output variable?

```
 print '%s' % (output)
```

the output may be 3 pages of data..

Thanks for the help.

Here is my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import subprocess


form = cgi.FieldStorage()
port = form.getvalue("port")
filename = form.getvalue("filename")
directory = form.getvalue("directory")
jobdir = '/var/www/jobs/' + filename


def createdir():
 os.system('mkdir /var/www/jobs/' + filename)
createdir()

def capout():
 output = os.system('/home/fsoft/cap/capnostic -r %s %s%s > %s%s' % (port, directory,     filename, jobdir, filename))
capout()

def htmlout():
 print 'Content-type: text/html\n'
 print '<html>'
 print '<head>'
 print '<title>Capnostic Output</title>'
 print '</head>'
 print '<body>'
 print '<BR><BR><BR><center>'
 print '<table border=0>'
 print '<TR>'
 print '<TD><center>port = %s<BR>filename = %s<BR>Directory = %s<BR>Job Directory = %s</TD>' % (port,filename,directory,jobdir)
 print '</TR>'
 print '</table>'
 print '<BR><BR><BR>'
 print '%s' % (output)
 print '</body>'
 print '</html>'

htmlout()
```

It is now telling me:

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: global name 'output' is not defined 
  args = ("global name 'output' is not defined",) 
  message = "global name 'output' is not defined"
```

Comment: `print '%s' % (output)` is probably redundant. If you can do that you should be able to just do `print output`.

Comment: According to the [official docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.system) `The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using os function`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `+` for concatenating your string and the spaces between your strings.  You can use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to simplify the task or just add a `+` and spaces where needed:

```
output = os.system('/home/fsoft/cap/capnostic -r %s %s%s > %s%s' % (port, 
                   directory, filename, jobdir, filename))
```

*Note: %s is used to treat each variable as a string.*

Usage of [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess.call#replacing-os-system) is replaced with the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
sts = os.system("mycmd" + " myarg")
# becomes 
sts = call("mycmd" + " myarg", shell=True)
```

To capture the output, you will want to use [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess.call#popen-objects), which would be translated as follows:

```
def capout():
   cmd = '/home/fsoft/cap/capnostic -r %s %s%s > %s%s' % (port, 
                       directory, filename, jobdir, filename)
   process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   output, error = process.communicate()
   return output

output = capout()
```

Comment: Note that won't get you the output of the command, it will just give the returncode and the user did specify that he would expect pages of data as the output.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  I got a little further along..  bvut now it is telling me:

    <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: global name 'output' is not defined 
      args = ("global name 'output' is not defined",) 
      message = "global name 'output' is not defined"

Comment: Its your scope.  `output` does not exist when you're trying to call it in your `htmlout()` function.

Comment: Thanks RobB I am used to bash.  I defined 'output' earlier in the code what you are saying is htmlout() does not know that output has been defined earlier in the code?

Comment: You executed the function which assigned the variable, but only for the local scope of that function.  I've updated my answer to show how to access it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `+` before the `'>'`

```
cmd = ('/home/fsoft/cap/capnostic -r' + port + directory + filename + '>' + 
        jobdir + filename)

os.system(cmd)
```

note that `os.system` does not return the output of the command, here is how you could get that:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = proc.communicate()
print output
```